# Restricting mailboxes to accept messages from specific external senders

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007, hosted-exchange

Here's the scenario: I have an MS Exchange distribution list called SMT. Currently, `msExchRequireAuthToSendTo` is set to `true`, so this list will not accept emails from external senders. We recently hired a new VP of something, and he uses an external email address, so he can't send to SMT.

After some Googling, I've discovered the `authOrig` and `dlMemSubmitPerms` attributes, which authorizes a list of senders, and members of a list of distribution lists respectively. I created an MS Exchange contact for the new VP's external address and added that to the `authOrig` list. Then I added the company wide distribution list to `dlMemSubmitPerms`. Finally, I set `msExchRequireAuthToSendTo` to `false`.

The company employees can send to SMT, but the external address still cannot. Is it because `authOrig` only works with MS Exchange users and not contacts?

According to [Understanding Recipient Restrictions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124405(EXCHG.80).aspx) you can:

> use this restriction ... for mail contacts that represent suppliers for a retail organization. You may want to configure each of these mail contacts to accept messages from only the buyers who work directly with those suppliers.

How can I accomplish this? (I know that the easiest solution is to make the VP use his internal address, but if I can cater to his wants, I'll get brownie points.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing like a nearly-year-late answer.  Being that I'm so late, you probably have this working already.

The settings you've mentioned should work exactly as you want, though I will admit that I rarely, if ever, set the AD attributes directly.  This is very easy to do within the Exchange PowerShell module (on Exchange 2007 / 2010).

```
Set-DistributionGroup [your_distribution_group] -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $false -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom [contact] -AcceptMessagesOnlyFromDLMembers [company-wide_distribution_group]
```

If it's still not working, could you post the NDR error the contact is receiving when trying to send?